# Write to CSV within PL/PgSQL loop without being superuser

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I would like to loop through a table in a PostgreSQL database, and use a variable `kommunekode` as a parameter and print it to a CSV. However, I can't get the copy to work. I am not the superuser of the database.

I can get the variable in my output by using `RAISE NOTICE`, so the variable works fine.

Current code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
kommunekode text;
BEGIN
FOR loop_counter IN 1..99 LOOP
SELECT komkode into kommunekode FROM (SELECT komkode, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY komkode) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT komkode FROM kommunekoder) komkode) as x where row_number = loop_counter;
/COPY (Select * From bbr.co40100t_geo where komkode = kommunekode) TO 'C:\Path.csv with csv delimiter ';
END LOOP;
end; $$
```

Current error:

```
ERROR:  cannot COPY to/from client in PL/pgSQL
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at SQL statement
```

Comment: First it should be `\copy` not `/copy`. But that still won't work. `\copy` is not a [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) so it can't be used inside of PL/pgSQL

Comment: Is there a method a can use to print to csv inside the PL/pgSQL?

Comment: You can do this from plpgsql: `EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT * ...) TO ...';`

Answer (score 0):

First, `\copy` is a `psql` command and not a PL/pgSQL or SQL command. You'll have to use `COPY`.

Second, if your intention is to write to a file on the client machine, you cannot do that in a function. How should code that runs on the database server access a file on the client machine?

If your intention is to write to a file on the database server without having superuser permissions, there are two ways:

- If you are using PostgresSQL v11 or better, grant the database user the `pg_write_server_files` role.
- Put the code inside a function that is owned by a superuser and defined with `SECURITY DEFINER`. Then it will run with superuser privileges regardless of who calls it. But **never do that without also using `SET search_path = pg_catalog` in the function definition** if you want to avoid security leaks.